# What are the pips and skin of an orange?

Tags: cake, language, oranges

> When the orange is soft and cold, cut in half and ***remove any pips***. Process the whole orange, ***including the skin***, until medium chunky

From: http://www.maryberry.co.uk/recipes/baking/whole-orange-spice-cake

Is skin the outer thick orange coloured cover?
or the fibrous threads that orange pieces have?
or the thin skin that holds the juice and seeds?

What are ***pips*** and ***skin*** of an orange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The skin is the outer thick orange-coloured cover; obviously as you're not told to remove it this would include the *pith* (the white fibrous material) as well. The pips are the seeds inside the fruit:

> **pip**
>
> *noun*
>
> plural noun: pips
>
> 1.
>   a small hard seed in a fruit.
>
> *synonyms:  seed, stone, pit*

Comment: So, it is telling me to put in "whole" orange in the cake? Is the cover not sour in taste?

Comment: The skin (or rather the white pith inside the skin) is somewhat bitter, yes, but seeing as you have over half a pound of sugar in there as well, I imagine that's been accounted for. British fruit-based cakes tend not to be so all-out sweet as those from other countries. Also, consider something like marmalade, which usually has shreds of skin in it. With citrus fruits, the majority of the flavour is in the skin itself, not the fruit inside.

Comment: No problem. Happy baking!